# How to set 24 hour time in laravel migration

Tags: laravel, time, migration, laravel-migrations

I have an input field that will provide me the 24 hour format time like 16:30, 18:22, 13:50 etc. So how to set migration column for this.
I read already documentation but not did not understand.

Comment: Instead of changing column type its better if you do it on your presentation layer or define at  your model level https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 2):

As [@M Khalid Junaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853360/m-khalid-junaid) has suggested, you should define a `mutator` for your attribute on your model to modify the value of a normal `timestamp`.

So firstly, you need to create the column in the migration:

```
$table->timestamp('your_column_name');
```

Then, you can create your mutator on your model just like any method. We are going to use `Carbon` to play around with the format. Keep in mind that the name of the mutator needs to be the *camelCase* of your column name:

```
protected function yourColumnName(): Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(
        get: fn ($value) => Carbon::parse($value)->format('H:i'),
    );
}
```